# Simultaneous equations with interaction terms

Tags: panel-data, stata, 2sls, simultaneous-equation

How do you estimate the following simultaneous equation model on a panel dataset?

$Y_1=\beta_1X_1Y_2 +\beta_2X_2+e_1$

$Y_2=\alpha_1X_1Y_1 +\alpha_2 X_3+e_2$

$Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are endogenous while $X_1, X_2$ and $X_3$ are exogenous.

Since I couldn't find a command that runs simultaneous equations for panel datasets in Stata, I wanted to derive the reduced form of the first equation and then run a 2sls model using **xtivreg** in Stata and then repeat the same procedure for the first equation. Will that be a correct approach?

Also, it seems that due to the interaction terms, I will end up with a nonlinear format for reduced equations in which the error term is correlated with the exogenous variable. This is how I derived the reduced form:

$Y_1=\beta_1X_1[\alpha_1X_1Y_1 +\alpha_2 X_3+e_2] +\beta_2X_2+e_1$

$Y_1=\beta_1\alpha_1X_1^2Y_1+\beta_1\alpha_2X_1X_3+\beta_1X_1e_2+e_1$

Does Stata handle nonlinear 2sls with panel data?

Will the fact that my new error term in the reduced form ($\beta_1X_1e_2+e_1$) is a function of $X_1$ have any ramifications? and if yes, how can I solve this?